# PowerBuilder: Disconnect the database on idle

Tags: powerbuilder

I have an application in PowerBuilder, and many users keeping it open unused for hours.
Sometimes, an operation forgets to commit; therefore, some table stay locked indefinitely, thus preventing everyone from working.
I tried to put all the commits in place, but it is really difficult to debug this in such a big application.
I would like to disconnect the database connection when the application is idle. This is not difficult, but my problem is, when the mouse or keyboard are touched, the application needs to re-open the connection. How do I do that? It is not acceptable to close the application every time it is idle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, I'd recommend you **not** take the easy way out, and get to work on closing all those transactions. If you have something uncommitted, aside from the locking issue, you have no idea if the next statement that *happens* to be executed is going to be a COMMIT or a ROLLBACK, nor which is now needed. My experience with this is that this kind of investigation always brings out other issues around the transaction. This issue is probably bigger than locks.

As for reconnecting, if you're going this route (obviously not my first choice), I'd recommend an alternative design: CONNECT when you *need* the connection next. Basically (if you were going to encapsulate the code inside a function in your transaction object):

```
IF DBHandle() = 0 THEN CONNECT using THIS;
```

If you've got a framework like PFC, then you'll likely only have a few places to code this. If you don't have a framework that encapsulates pieces of work like retrieve and update, then you're about to wish that you did. Still might be better than bogging down your performance by checking a database connection on every keystroke and mouse movement.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Terry can you be more specific? The app-freezing-bug when idle is the most annoying thing we have "inherited" after we migrated from SQL Server 2000 to 2005/8 (from MSS to SNC).

Comment: @PanosPlat: I'm not really clear what you're asking clarification on.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the mousemove and key events. When one of these fires, issue a CONNECT; statement.

See:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc37781_1150/html/psref/BFCCFFGH.htm